# how to get path of picture taken by camera ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I was using the imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate method for getting the url of the image which user chose on photo gallery. But when I try to get URL for image taken by camera its return nill.
Here is my code.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if (imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedImage, nil, nil, nil)

            if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
                let imageURL =  info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
                print(imageURL)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image you have taken is not saved and has not any name yet. You need to save the image before you can get the path for the image. That´s why it returns `nil`.

If you select an image from the image library instead of taking one with the camera you´ll get a path.

Comment: Exactly if I pic any photo from library its return the path. But, I have the requirement of taking photo from camera. And I tried with this code to save it `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pickedImage, nil, nil, nil)` it saving in in photo Library and I can see it. but still its return nil.

Comment: @Sarath. what you need to do is that you need to save the path that you´re saving the image to. So save the path + file name and there you have your path to the image.

Answer (score 1):

Rashwan L Answer worked for me as well and I was not able to save image with UIImageToSavedPhotoAlbum so written CameraImageManager class method for saving, loading and getting URL for upload image. You can also make it as extension of Image and URL

```
class CameraImageManager {

   static func saveImage(imageName: String, image: UIImage) {

        guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }

        let fileName = imageName
        let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return }

        //Checks if file exists, removes it if so.
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: fileURL.path)
                print("Removed old image")
            } catch let removeError {
                print("couldn't remove file at path", removeError)
            }

        }

        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
        } catch let error {
            print("error saving file with error", error)
        }

    }

    static func getImagePathFromDiskWith(fileName: String) -> URL? {

        let documentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory

        let userDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentDirectory, userDomainMask, true)

        if let dirPath = paths.first {
            let imageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            return imageUrl
        }

        return nil
    }

   static func loadImageFromDiskWith(fileName: String) -> UIImage? {

        let documentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory

        let userDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentDirectory, userDomainMask, true)

        if let dirPath = paths.first {
            let imageUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageUrl.path)
            return image

        }

        return nil
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

After you saved the image into the Photos Album, you can get the path in response callback

```
func saveImage(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(image(path:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

@objc private func image(path: String, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    debugPrint(path) // That's the path you want
}
```

Comment: Can you please look into this as i was confused with this code. I'm calling saveImage method like
`saveImage(image: pickedImage, completion: {_ in 
                    print("Image saved completed") }`
 and in the didFinishSavinWithError method assingning a path to variable.Im getting CRASH.

Comment: what's your crash?

Comment: @noir_eagle this is the crash: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @noir_eagle I am also facing same crash :(

Comment: thats when someone throws untested code, you get crashes and waste of time